# Passing HTML into my component

Tags: html, angular, angular-components

Consider the following component `sidebar.component.html`:

```
<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li class="tooltipped" data-position="right" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Go to the dashboard">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="material-icons">home</i>
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tooltipped" data-position="right" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Manage your times">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="material-icons">watch_later</i>
        <span>Times</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tooltipped" data-position="right" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Go to settings">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In `app.component.html`, I use the sidebar using its tags (`<sidebar>`). However, now I want to make it so that the `<li>` elements are given inside the `<sidebar>` tags so that they are no longer inside `sidebar.component.html` to make the component re-usable.

I'm not sure what this is called and I am having trouble finding it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't get what the problem is. Perhaps `<ng-content></ng-content>` for transclusion?

Comment: I updated the post for clarity, I will try out <ng-content> thanks.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Create a sidebar component with an `<ng-content>` where the passed children should be displayed

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  template: '<ul><ng-content></ng-content></ul>'
})
export class SidebarComponent {
}
```

and use it like

```
<sidebar>
    <li class="tooltipped" data-position="right" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Go to the dashboard">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="material-icons">home</i>
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tooltipped" data-position="right" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Manage your times">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="material-icons">watch_later</i>
        <span>Times</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="tooltipped" data-position="right" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Go to settings">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="material-icons">settings</i>
      </a>
    </li>
</sidebar>
```

Comment: Yes, this works as intended! However, what is the behavior with CSS? My styling does no longer apply to the elements, however I can't see any changes in the HTML that would induce a change in my selectors.

Comment: The change is that Angular adds `_ng_context-xxx` attributes and rewrites your styles before it adds them to the DOM. You need to add `:host /deep/ li {}` or similar to make styles cross component boundaries.

Comment: Alright thanks, I got enough information to get me going!